# Gulp error - Error: Cannot find module 'sigmund'

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

My Gulp was working fine until I installed browser-sync

`npm install browser-sync gulp --save-dev`

Then I started to get this error:

> Error: Cannot find module 'lru-cache'

Which I solved using this: `npm link lru-cache` answer from https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/1154

However, now when I try to run `gulp` I get this new error:

> ~/Projects/starfeeder
>       ❯ npm install browser-sync gulp --save-dev
>       npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
>       npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module instead
>
> fsevents@1.1.2 install 
>       /Users/leongaban/Projects/starfeeder/node_modules/fsevents
>   node install

My gulpfile if that helps:

```
"use strict";
const gulp        = require('gulp'),
      _           = require('lodash'), // https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash
      del         = require('del'), // https://www.npmjs.com/package/del
      fs          = require('fs'), // Node file system
      gutil       = require('gulp-util'), // https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-util
      htmlReplace = require('gulp-html-replace'), // https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-html-replace
      notify      = require("gulp-notify"), // https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-notify
      runSequence = require('run-sequence'), // https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-sequence
      sass        = require('gulp-ruby-sass'), // https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-ruby-sass
      sourcemaps  = require('gulp-sourcemaps'); // https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sourcemaps

const rootPath = process.cwd();

const paths = {
    files: ['src/static/**']
};

const errorlog = err => {
    gutil.log(gutil.colors.red.bold.inverse('  ERROR: '+err));
    this.emit('end');
};

// Build tasks chain ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
gulp.task('build', function(cb) {
    runSequence(
        'build:app-css',      // Minify and concat app styles
        'build:move-files',
        'build:index',        // Replace scripts in index.html
        'build:final', cb);   // Remove app.min.js from build folder
});

gulp.task('build:move-files', () => gulp.src(paths.files).pipe(gulp.dest('starfeeder/')) );

// Preprocess SASS into CSS \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
gulp.task('build:app-css', () => sass('src/sass/starfeeder.scss', { style: 'compressed' }).on('error', errorlog).pipe(gulp.dest('src/static/css/')) );

// Clear out all files and folders from build folder \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
gulp.task('build:cleanfolder', cb => { del(['starfeeder/**'], cb); });

// Task to make the index file production ready \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
gulp.task('build:index', () => {
    process.stdout.write(gutil.colors.white.inverse(' New asset paths in markup: \n'));
    process.stdout.write(gutil.colors.yellow(' static/css/starfeeder.css\n'));

    gulp.src('index.html')
        .pipe(htmlReplace({
            'app-css': 'css/starfeeder.css'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('starfeeder/'))
        .pipe(notify('Starfeeder build created!'));
});

gulp.task('build:final', cb => {
    process.stdout.write(gutil.colors.blue.bold   ('######################################################     \n'));
    process.stdout.write(gutil.colors.blue.inverse('               Starfeeder build created!                   \n'));
    process.stdout.write(gutil.colors.blue.bold   ('######################################################     \n'));
});

// Main Styles /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
gulp.task('app-css', () => {
    return sass('src/sass/starfeeder.scss', { style: 'compressed' })
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .on('error', errorlog)
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./maps'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('src/static/css/'))
});

// Development watch /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// ☕️⏎→
gulp.task('watch', () => {
    gulp.watch('src/sass/**/*.scss', ['app-css']).on('change', file => {
        let filePath = file.path.split(rootPath);
        logFileChanged(filePath[1]);
    });
});

gulp.task('default', ['watch']);
```

Comment: Have you tried upgrading your gulp itself?

Comment: I installed gulp fresh, however just got it working again... crazy strange tho, posting what I found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so still not sure why I got those errors, but never installing browserSync again.

I had to `npm link` all my gulp plugins.

That work, but then it broke during the `gulp build` process.

Instead of doing `npm link` to everything, included other node modules I've never heard off. I removed `browserSync` and deleted my **node_modules** folder and did `yarn(npm) install`.

Comment: Ah, I faced similar problems. Good to know that browserSync might cause those strange caching errors.

Comment: It's not browserSync. Same thing happened when I installed through2

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue with installing `through2`. The project used shrink wrap and had a `package-lock.json` which caused the a dependencies to break. Once I removed the lock and re-installed, all was good.